# Apache continuously restarting

Tags: apache, restart

I have a problem with my Apache2 (Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.2n PHP/7.1.13 configured).
The webserver restarts continuously every 5-30 minutes.

Eventlog:

```
Name der fehlerhaften Anwendung: httpd.exe, Version: 2.4.27.0, Zeitstempel: 0x5961fa06
Name des fehlerhaften Moduls: ntdll.dll, Version: 6.1.7601.23391, Zeitstempel: 0x56e9a698
Ausnahmecode: 0xc0000005
Fehleroffset: 0x000820ec
ID des fehlerhaften Prozesses: 0x1018
Startzeit der fehlerhaften Anwendung: 0x01d3babbe3f52ac9
Pfad der fehlerhaften Anwendung: C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
Pfad des fehlerhaften Moduls: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
Berichtskennung: 40ebf6a1-26b2-11e8-a4fa-005056b218d8
```

The webserver holds web-applications like mediawiki, redmine, moodle, joomla etc.

I started logging httpd in debug level and saw the following before every restart:

```
[Tue Mar 13 12:10:24.818192 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2940:tid 1788] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 10.1.100.4:56418] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://mediawiki.contoso.com/Hauptseite
[Tue Mar 13 12:10:24.818192 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2940:tid 1788] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 10.1.100.4:56418] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://mediawiki.contoso.com/Hauptseite
[Tue Mar 13 12:10:24.833792 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2940:tid 1780] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 10.1.100.4:56419] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://mediawiki.contoso.com/Hauptseite
[Tue Mar 13 12:10:24.833792 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2940:tid 1780] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 10.1.100.4:56419] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://mediawiki.contoso.com/Hauptseite
[Tue Mar 13 12:10:25.130198 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2940:tid 1780] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 10.1.100.4:56419] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://mediawiki.contoso.com/Hauptseite
[Tue Mar 13 12:10:25.130198 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2940:tid 1780] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 10.1.100.4:56419] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://mediawiki.contoso.com/Hauptseite
[Tue Mar 13 12:10:25.379803 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2940:tid 1780] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 10.1.100.4:56419] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://mediawiki.contoso.com/Hauptseite
[Tue Mar 13 12:10:25.379803 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2940:tid 1780] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 10.1.100.4:56419] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://mediawiki.contoso.com/Hauptseite
[Tue Mar 13 12:10:26.097417 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2148:tid 324] AH00428: Parent: child process 2940 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
```

Further research pointing out that the problem occurs when someone wants to log into mediawiki 1.29.1 and is following this link:

http://mediawiki.contoso.com/index.php?title=Spezial:Anmelden&returnto=Hauptseite

Error analysis is difficult because the failure occurs sporadically.

It would be nice if you can help me with this problem.

Please let me now if you need further information.

Comment: When I disable APCu ($wgMainCacheType = CACHE_ACCEL;) it seems to work.
I'll log until tomorrow.

Comment: Disabling APCu in php.ini does the trick. No more restarts.
But what's wrong with APCu?